# Custom permalinks with NextGEN Gallery

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, plugin-nextgen-gallery

i set my wordpress permlink to `/%category%/%postname%` now i'm using Nextgen Gallery so when i have a gallery in a page it will be something like `/cat/page?gallery=10` i want to make it something like `cat/page/gallery id/` i tried alot with wp_rewrite ... but no luck ... any help ?

this is what i'm testing on .. it's not my code it's provided from wordpress ... i will put everything in its place when i found the way ... so don't worry i will not `flushRules` on `init` ... thanks a lot

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','wp_insertMyRewriteRules');
add_filter('query_vars','wp_insertMyRewriteQueryVars');
add_filter('init','flushRules');

// Remember to flush_rules() when adding rules
function flushRules(){
 global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

// Adding a new rule
function wp_insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
 $newrules = array();

    //i don't know what should i put here
 $newrules[''] = '';
 return $newrules + $rules;
 //
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function wp_insertMyRewriteQueryVars($vars)
{
    array_push($vars, 'id');
    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the [rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)? Maybe this can solve your problem?
If you use the rewrite API, then you probably should turn of NextGen rewrite function.

Answer (score 1):

### With an extra endpoint

Since you want to add something to the end of every post/page rewrite rule, you probably can just add a *rewrite endpoint*. These are regexes of the form `/[endpoint_name](/[optional_extra_stuff])?` that are appended to the already generated rules for pages, posts, archives, ...

You define on which structures you want to add them by setting the *endpoint mask*. This is a bitmask, so you can combine different groups using the `|` operator, like this: `EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES` will match for every page and every permalink (full post and date-based archives). The default list of endpoints can be found [at the top of `wp-includes/rewrite.php`.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.2/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L96)

The following code will add `/gallery(/(.*))?` to the existing rewrite rules for pages, posts and date-based archives (for some reason they are generated twice, once in `EP_PERMALINK` and once in `EP_DATE`):

```
add_filter( 'init', 'wpse4498_init' );
function wpse4498_init()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'gallery', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
}
```

### With explicit new rewrite rules

You can also do is explicitly, which might give you more control over the generated rules.

The rewrite rule itself it quite easy: take the generic post rule `(.+?)/([^/]+)` (`category/pagename`) and add your gallery structure. NextGEN always adds its query vars, not only when permalinks are enabled, so we can just use the `gallery` var:

```
'(.+?)/([^/]+)/gallery/([0-9]{1,})/?$' =>
    'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]&gallery=$matches[3]'
```

The placement of your extra rewrite rule is tricky. Since your permalink structure is `/%category%/%postname%/` you have verbose rewrite rules, and can't put a generic `(.+?)/([^/]+)` at the top: your pages will stop working. You can't put it at the bottom, as the attachment rules are quite generic and will have matched the URL before it reaches your rule. I think the best place to add it is with the `post_rewrite_rules` filter. This will give the following:

```
add_filter( 'post_rewrite_rules', 'wpse4498_post_rewrite_rules' );
function wpse4498_post_rewrite_rules( $post_rewrite_rules )
{
    $post_rewrite_rules = array(
        '(.+?)/([^/]+)/gallery/([0-9]{1,})/?$' =>
            'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]&gallery=$matches[3]',
    ) + $post_rewrite_rules;
    return $post_rewrite_rules;
}
```

This only covers posts, if you also want to support pages with galleries it will become much more complicated since you have to add them for each verbose page group.

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the permalinks in the NextGen settings? Under Gallery -> Options -> General select 'activate permalinks', then reset your general permalink settings once. It's not the cleanest URL in the world (it grabs the page ID instead of the name) but it does the job.

Comment: yes i did that, but i'm not happy with the ID thing ... plus the project description the page URL should be cat/page/gallery name/ is that possible ? Thanks a lot for your answer ..

Comment: Probably not without hacking the plugin itself, since it creates the rewrite rules. the other option would be to create pages with the hierarchy you want, then place each gallery individually.

Comment: hmmmmmm ... but i edited the plugin so every image has it's own page ... i can't create a page for every image ... plus my website content is dynamic

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear. not a page for each image, rather, a page for each gallery.